# Parse "ps aux" Linux terminal output with Ruby

Tags: ruby, linux

I am trying to make a program that parse output from the Linux command `ps aux` where the output can look like this:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    20:04   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   20:04   0:00 [rcu_gp]
root         4  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   20:04   0:00 [rcu_par_gp]
root       397  0.0  0.1  95112 15236 ?        S<s  20:04   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-journald
root       431  0.0  0.0  46588  4640 ?        Ss   20:04   0:01 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
and so on...
```

I run ps aux like this:

```
def run_ps_aux()
    ps_aux = `ps aux`
    return run_ps_aux
end

puts run_ps_aux()
```

I am however only interested in CPU, MEM and the COMMAND. I would like to get the output like this:

COMMAND:CPU:MEM

COMMAND:CPU:MEM

COMMAND:CPU:MEM

and so on...

Also, is it posible to sort so I will only get the 3 commands that have the highest CPU usage?

Appreciate all help!

Comment: You haven't showed us an attempt to solve the problem you're asking about. See "[ask]" and all its linked pages. Without evidence of effort showing us what you tried it looks like you didn't try, and want us to write the code for you, which is off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
%x{ ps aux }.lines # split string by newlines
            .drop(1) # skip the first line
            .map do |line| # iterate through the lines and return a new array
               columns= line.split(/\s+/, 11) # split line by one or more spaces
              "#{columns.last}:#{columns[2]}:#{columns[3]}"
            end
```

```
=> ["splash:0.0:0.2", "[kthreadd]:0.0:0.0", "[rcu_gp]:0.0:0.0", "[rcu_par_gp]:0.0:0.0", "[kworker/0:0H-kblockd]:0.0:0.0", "[mm_percpu_wq]:0.0:0.0", "[ksoftirqd/0]:0.0:0.0", "[rcu_sched]:0.0:0.0", "[migration/0]:0.0:0.0", "[idle_inject/0]:0.0:0.0", "[cpuhp/0]:0.0:0.0", "[kdevtmpfs]:0.0:0.0", "[netns]:0.0:0.0", "[rcu_tasks_kthre]:0.0:0.0", "[kauditd]:0.0:0.0", "[khungtaskd]:0.0:0.0", "[oom_reaper]:0.0:0.0", "[writeback]:0.0:0.0", "[kcompactd0]:0.0:0.0", "[ksmd]:0.0:0.0", ...
```

If you want something more reusable you can return an array of hashes instead:

```
lines = %x{ ps aux }.lines
headers = lines.first.split(/\s+/)
               .map{|h| h.tr('%', '').downcase.intern }
lines.drop(1).map do |line|
  # creates a hash from an array of pairs
  Hash[headers.zip(line.split(/\s+/, 11))]
end
```

```
[{:user=>"root", :pid=>"1", :cpu=>"0.0", :mem=>"0.3", :vsz=>"166932", :rss=>"6328", :tty=>"?", :stat=>"Ss", :start=>"May17", :time=>"0:03", :command=>"/sbin/init"}, {:user=>"root", :pid=>"2", :cpu=>"0.0", :mem=>"0.0", :vsz=>"0", :rss=>"0", :tty=>"?", :stat=>"S", :start=>"May17", :time=>"0:00", :command=>"[kthreadd]"}, ...]
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, this is great. I will accept this. However, the command gets cut if containing a space, for instance /usr/sbin/sshd -D -p 2222 does not include -D -p 2222. Once again, many thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Hmm the regex pattern might need a little improvement to deal with that case.

Comment: @max In that case, you can replace `line.split(/\s+/)` with `line.split(/\s+/, 11)`.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way IMHO is to run this shell command:

```
$ ps aux | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $11 ":" $3 ":" $4}'
```

or

```
$ ps aux | tail -n +2 | awk 'BEGIN {OFS=":"} {print $11, $3, $4}'
```

You can embed this command into your Ruby program.